# Python - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple Python snippet here which copies Macros Excel sheet into csvs. The snippet blows up for some odd reason. I used to run this snippet with `Python 2.7` and had no problem with it. I recently downloaded `Python 3.6`. How can I fix this issue?

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('P:/LFC Lots and Sales-NEW.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))
print ("Sheets copied")
```

Traceback:

```
writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! All I needed to do was change the `wb` to `w`.

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('P:/LFC Lots and Sales-NEW.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))
print ("Sheets copied")
```

Comment: With python 3, you'll also want `newline=''` in your open -- see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and read footnote #1.